# How to progressively increase the dimensionality of a matrix in Matlab/Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

How can I progressively increase the matrix dimensionality by adding a new value to the matrix as bellow?

```
octave:1> A = 1;
octave:2> A(1,2) = 1; 
octave:3> A(1,1,2) = 1;
octave:4> A(1,1,1,2) = 1;
octave:5> A(1,1,1,1,2) = 1;
octave:6> A(1,1,1,1,1,2) = 1;
 ...
and so on, N times
```

Comment: Just like that? What you have shown is valid. What would you like to be different?

Comment: What is the use case? It would help in phrasing an answer.

Comment: I want to add a new dimension N times, where N is a parameter.

Comment: Yes, you stated that in the question. My question is why you want to do this. It is typically better to create a matrix of the right sizes before starting your computation, rather than growing it. Growing it by adding dimensions is even more unusual than growing it by adding elements to existing dimensions. Understanding what you want to accomplish with this would help in providing a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

To create an array with an arbitrary number of dimensions in Octave, just use `vec`. Like so:

```
n = 7; # number of dimensions
x = [1 1]; # you must have at least two elements
vec (x, n)
```

Because Octave trims trailing singleton dimensions, the last dimension must not be a singleton which means your array must always have at least 2 elements.

Alternatively, you can also specify the size when creating an array with `ones` or a similar function and compute the size programmatically:

```
n = 7;
x = ones ([repmat(1, 1, n-1) 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an array with the desired number of elements, then used `reshape` to set it to the desired dimensionality. Then, to set each element, it is necessary to use the linear indexing, since the code needs to run for any number of dimensions.

```
c=zeros(1,2^m);
if m > 1, c=reshape(c,2*ones(1,m)); endif;
c(1)=1;
for i=0:m-1, c(2^i+1)=1; endfor
```

For example, if `m = 4` the we will get the desired result

```
octave:6> [c(1,1,1,1), c(2,1,1,1), c(1,2,1,1), c(1,1,2,1), c(1,1,1,2)]
ans =

   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: This does not match your question, though. You're not progressively increasing the dimensionality. If you want to write code that works with a matrix of arbitrary dimensionality, then ask about that. I could suggest better workflows that what you're doing so far. Note that your first two lines of code can be replaced with `c=zeros(2*ones(1,m))`. For indexing there are neat things you can do, for example `indx={1,1,2,1}; c(idx{:})` -- create a cell array with the appropriate indexing first.